# Windows 8.1 VirtualBox: Mouse cursor is black ugly graphics-error style box

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04, mouse-cursor, guest-additions

I have installed Windows 8.1 on VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.04.

It works, however I have a problem with the mouse-integration feature of the guest additions (4.3.24).

Whenever, the pointer transforms into a cursor I get a big black ugly graphics-error style box around the cursor, making it practically unusable. It works fine except when hovering over textfields. What is the remedy to this ugly mouse-pointer error?

If I turn of mouse-integration it works, however the mouse is too slow and I have to press right-controll all the time to switch, which is really annoying.

Comment: Seems likte this problem: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (at least partially).

Install a new [Windows mouse scheme](http://www.7tutorials.com/top-10-best-mouse-cursor-schemes-windows)